# fundamental groups of curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gt.geometric-topology

I saw the following statement made without proof in a paper of Bogomolov and Tschinkel:

If $X$ is an algebraic surface, and $C$ is an ample smooth curve in $X,$ then the fundamental group of $C$ surjects onto that of $X.$

I was wondering if someone could supply a reference, and perhaps some idea of what the most general version of this statement was...

Comment: This statement goes back to Zariski and Lefschetz, but it
is usually proved by Morse theory now days.  (If it wasn't so late
I'd say more.)

Comment: It will be earlier tomorrow :)

Comment: You're right, it is, and you have answers too.
Regarding, your comment below. Ample means that a multiple
is equivalent (in the appropriate sense) to a hyperplane section, or if you prefer that the associated line bundle is positive (by Kodaira).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a general Lefschetz hyperplane theorem for the homotopy groups of an ample divisor $D$ on a smooth complex variety $X$. Basically, this theorem says that the relative homotopy groups $\pi_i(X,D)$ are zero for all $i$ less than $\dim X$. In particular, the map $\pi_1(D)\to\pi_1(X)$ is an isomorphism for $\dim X\ge 3$ and surjective for $\dim X= 2$. There is a very nice proof of this theorem using Morse theory which can be found in Lazarsfeld's book 'Positivity in algebraic geometry'.

Comment: That is a a nice theorem! (I fixed a small typo in your LaTeX, hope you don't mind)

Comment: Ah, the right reference seems to be the following paper of Raoul Bott's:

R. Bott

On a theorem of Lefschetz

Michigan Math Journal, 1959 

(Bott attributes the result to Thom).

Comment: I did not notice @J.C.'s (or @David's) edit -- the version I saw missed the last three lines. I will check out Lazarsfeld's book as well (which can, hopefully, also shed light on when ampleness can/should be expected -- as a non-algebraic-geometer I have little feeling for what it means...)


Comment: another standard reference for this classical result of Lefschetz is Milnor, Morse theory, p. 41-42.

Answer (score 8):

There is also an algebraic proof which works over fields of positive characteristic.

See, e.g., Lemma 5.1 of the paper [Zariski's conjecture and related problems](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=ASENS_1983_4_16_2_305_0) by Madhav Nori (Annales scientifiques de l'École Normale
Supérieure, Sér. 4, 16 no. 2 (1983), p. 305-344).

The proof of that Lemma is more general than what you need. It goes as follows. Let $X$ be a proper smooth algebraic surface and let $A\subset X$ be an ample curve. That $\pi_1(A)$ surjects onto $\pi_1(X)$ means the following: any finite étale cover $f:Y\to X$ which is split over $A$ is split. So if $Y$ is connected, $\deg(f)=1$.

Let us prove that if $A$ is ample; in fact, we only need $A$ big and nef.
If $f$ has a section on $A$, one can write $f^{-1}(A)=B+R$ where $B\to A$
is an isomorphism, and $R$ is disjoint from $B$. The Hodge index theorem
says that the intersection form restricted to the space generated by $B$ and $R$ has
at most one +-sign. Since $(B+R)^2=(f^*A)^2=\deg(f) A^2>0$, it has exactly one +-sign,
and the determinant
$$\begin{vmatrix} (B+R)^2 & (B+R)\cdot B \cr  B\cdot (B+R) & B^2\end{vmatrix}
$$
is nonpositive. By the projection formula, one has
$$(B+R)\cdot B=f^*A\cdot B=A\cdot f_*B=A^2.$$
Since $B$ and $R$ are disjoint, we obtain $B^2=A^2$. Then,
$$  \deg(f)A^2 = (B+R)^2=B^2+R^2, $$
so $$R^2=(\deg(f)-1) A^2$$.
The above determinant is equal to
$ (\deg(f)-1)A^2$. Since $A^2>0$, $\deg(f)\leq 1$.

This proof generalizes to the so-called Ramanujam lemma according to which an effective divisor on a surface which is big and nef is numerically connected (doesn't decompose as the sum of two nonzero effective divisors with 0-intersection), hence connected. In our case, the existence of the section implies that $f^*A$ is not numerically connected; it is however big and nef because this property is stable under finite pull-back.

See also the paper of J-B. Bost, [Potential theory and Lefschetz theorems for arithmetic surfaces](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=ASENS_1999_4_32_2_241_0) (Annales scientifiques de l'École Normale Supérieure, Sér. 4, 32 no. 2 (1999), p. 241-312) where this argument is explained for surfaces and adapted for arithmetic
surfaces.

Comment: This is very nice!